# Using microtype protrusion with XeTeX and Ubuntu

Tags: xetex, ubuntu, microtype, file-lookup

I believe I have all the correct versions of the software at hand and installed (v. 2.5 of microtype and .9998 of XeTeX) to get protrusion to work with XeTeX on my Ubuntu system but I keep getting an error when compiling.  Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

But when I attempt to compile with `xelatex microtest.tex` I get:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./microtest.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation,     lo
aded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)


! LaTeX Error: File `microtype-xetex.def' not found.
```

I have microtype-xetex.def installed in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist-tex/latex/microtype:

```
pwd
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype
ls
letterspace.sty       mt-bch.cfg        mt-eus.cfg               mt-ppl.cfg
microtype.cfg         mt-blg.cfg        mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg  mt-ptm.cfg
microtype.lua         mt-CharisSIL.cfg  mt-msa.cfg               mt-ugm.cfg
microtype-luatex.def  mt-cmr.cfg        mt-msb.cfg               mt-zpeu.cfg
microtype-pdftex.def  mt-euf.cfg        mt-mvs.cfg
microtype.sty         mt-eur.cfg        mt-pad.cfg
microtype-xetex.def   mt-euroitc.cfg    mt-pmn.cfg
```

I've copied those files over to other spots but I keep getting the same error. Is there perhaps some kind of install script I was supposed to run or compile? All I did was copy the extracted files I downloaded to this directory (replacing the `microtype` files that were already there).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Did you issue `sudo texhash`?

Comment: That was it exactly. I had no idea. Thank you very much.

Comment: @bfootdav how did you install microtype v 2.5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TeX systems relies on a cache for finding files, in order to reduce search time in its *huge* directories.

The main trees all have at their top level a file named `ls-R` that contains a tree representation of the subdirectories and their contents.

When a new file is installed in a directory in the main tree, the cache needs to be updated by

```
sudo texhash
```

However, it's not a good idea to modify the directories in the main tree because they might be restored during an update and you'd end up with an unstable TeX system.

All TeX distributions maintain a "local" tree, which you can find the location of with the shell command

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
```

On my machine it is

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

You can create the relevant subtree with

```
sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/microtype
```

and then copy the files belonging to the `microtype` package in the created directory by

```
sudo cp * $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/microtype
```

assuming you are in a work directory containing the downloaded file. A new

```
sudo texhash
```

will enable you to work with `microtype` version 2.5 without touching the original, since the "local" tree is looked at before the main tree.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have now installed the microtype package in the appropriate local directory and everything is working perfectly.